# how to animate text over an image button like windows phone( flipping text 360 around z axis)

Tags: android, animation, text

I have a text over an image button all things are set, but i am thinking to animate this text like wndows phone(windows 8) . Any ideas how to do that through xml or java (xml prefer) as i am bit slow in java. Please help , thanks in advance struggling with this problem over a week.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) you can find all you want to know about animation. Good luck!