# How to animate my button layout like windows 8 slide in button tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I would like to animate my button layout which is hightlighted in image,the animation should be like when i touch the right most corner of the screen it should be visible and when i have select the button and touch the main layout it should vanish or become invisible.

i an fair idea in Making the layout visible and invisible using the visibility option,but the animation of the layout is what i am looking for.

[image]

Can anyone guide me pls,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804500/how-to-animate-text-over-an-image-button-like-windows-phone-flipping-text-360-a/18806774#18806774

Comment: @Naddy Thanks for the share,android hive gives examples for an button click animation,Its works gd for me,But i would like to animate only when user touches the right end corner.Any help pls

Comment: You can take the right end corner inside a `LinearLayout` or any other container and animate it just like you animate a `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a frame layout with transparent background at right corner of the screen and add a touch listener to this layout.Handle the visible and gone state inside this touch listener.